# D3.JS Dynamically replace <tspan>

Tags: d3.js, dynamic, replace, typography, tspan

I am using sunburst example as a basis and trying to change multi-lined
caption on clicking with a new data. The *click function* looks like this:

```
function click(d) {

text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);

console.log(d.depth);

path.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))

.each("start", function(e, i) {

    if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx))

    {
        var replaceText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text")
        replaceText.remove("tspan")

        var tspan = replaceText.append("tspan")
            .attr("class", "sunburst2")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("TEST");

    }

})

//each
.each("end", function(e, i) {

    if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx))

    {

        var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text")

        arcText.transition().duration(750)
            .attr("opacity", 1)
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + getCentroid(d) + ")rotate(" + textRotation(d) + ")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")


    }

});
//end of each
```

}

PS: In this example the initial captions should be replaced by "TEST".

But it doesn't work and show nothing. What I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: In the same time this piece of code

`.each("start", function(e, i) {


                        if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx)) 


                        {
                            var replaceText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text")

                            replaceText.select("tspan")

                            .text("TEST")

     
                        }

                    
                    })`

do replacement of the first tspan element

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution through experiments.
Instead of using `replaceText.remove("tspan")` you should use `replaceText.selectAll("*").remove();`

Bingo!